can i change global variable using future.apply package
Here's a toy example.
I want to write values to the cnt variable as in the example with lapply
cnt <- NULL
f <- function(i) cnt <<- i
la <- lapply(1:5, f)

.
cnt 
[1] 5

I'm using an external cnt variable rather than an la result because I want to be able to manually stop and resume the process.
My problem is that I don't know how to do the same with future_lapply
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)

cnt <- NULL
fla <- future_lapply(1:5, f) 

.
cnt 
NULL


Probably a good start is reading and understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition . For example parLapply would give a nice hint with cannot change value of locked binding for 'cnt'.

I suggest you let the workers write i to files. I don't understand how knowing i does allow you to stop and resume.
